# Some Fields Not Saving - Laravel 5.1 Registration

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem when creating new user in Laravel 5.1

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
  use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'laravel_users';

public $timestamps = false;


protected $primaryKey = 'id';


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    'role_id',
                    'email',
                    'avatar',
                    'isActive',
                ];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

public function isAdministrator()
{
    return false;
}

public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Blog');
}
}
```

authcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

#use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Redirect;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
//temporarily redirected to duterte-run.mendanielle.com
public function getRegister()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function redirectToProvider()
{

    return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{

    //retrieve user's information from facebook
    $user  = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();
}
}
```

I have no idea why email field is not saving and php artisan tinker returns no error

Also, mysql fields is correct and manually adding values inside mysql commands works.Any idea on this?

Comment: Is it an email/password user that's not working, or a Github socialite user?

Comment: @andrewtweber I created a form that allows Github socialite and traditional login into one form.I don't know if it's the right way,since I am new to Laravel, As you can see, the redirect and callback function for socialite is 'embedded' in AuthController that houses the email/password for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your email & password code. You have the `email` attribute inside `$fillable`, and you added it to the `create` method, so if there's still a problem there then maybe you have the form field named incorrectly.

If you're talking about the Socialite Github user, your `handleProviderCallback` method is far from complete. Socialite will give you some user data, but then it's up to you to take that data and convert it into your app's User Eloquent model, and log that user in.

```php
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $fb_user = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();

    // Check if the email is already registered
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $fb_user->getEmail())->first();

    // If not, create a new user
    if (! $user->exists) {
        // Grab data from Facebook
        $data = [
            'username' => $fb_user->getNickname(),
            'email'    => $fb_user->getEmail(),
            'password' => str_random(40),
        ];

        // Use it to create an Eloquent user object
        $user = $this->create($data);
    }

    // Log that user in
    \Auth::login($user);

    // Direct them to the authenticated users page
    return redirect('home');
}
```

This is still just a shell, you'll have to handle cases where the email/username are already taken, etc.